# How to remove all single occurring new lines "\n", but not multiple lines

Tags: replace, sed

I want to remove in a file all `\n` tags, but not `\n\n` tags

Here is an example:

```
this
is 

a test
```

should be:

```
thisis

a test
```

I have tried to manipulating using `sed ':a;N;s/\n/g'`, but without success.

Comment: What should happen if there are three newlines in a row?

Comment: I don't have the situation

Comment: Du you like `thisis` or `this is` as output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk` you can try this:

```
awk '{$1=$1}1' RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" file
this is

a test
```

Edit: another `awk` variation

```
awk '{printf "%s ",$0} !NF {print "\n"}' file
```

Last one shorten some:

```
awk '{printf "%s "(!NF?"\n\n":""),$0}' file
```

If you do not like the space between fields and get `thisis` just remove space after `%s` like this:

```
awk '{printf "%s"(!NF?"\n\n":""),$0}' file
or
awk '{printf (!NF?RS RS:x) $0}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

One way with `sed` would be:

```
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\([^\n]\)\n\([^\n]\)/\1\2/g' file
thisis

a test
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl solution:

```bsh
perl -pe '/./ and chomp or print "\n"' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;/\n$/!s/\n//;ta' file
```